# Split a string of news based on certain rules

Tags: python, string

I would like to split a string like the one below:

```
string = "Lines: 67 \n\nThis is an example"
```

Note that the "67" is just example, sometimes we have "315" or "6666" which is undetermined number of digits. I know we can use regex but I do not know how to apply it.

Another note: Sometimes the string can be something like this too.

```
"Lines: 6777       \nThis is an example"

string = string.split("Lines:")
```

Current results:

```
["", " 67 \n\nThis is an example"]
```

Expected results:

```
["Lines: 67", " \n\nThis is an example"] #If possible I wish the string[1] to have no front space. So maybe I can use ".strip"?
```

Comment: Sorry, I make some changes. I do not want to split the Lines to start with but I wanted to split it after the "Lines: 67" which is right after the end of the digit.

Comment: The example is just what I tried but of course is a wrong one because I need the Lines to be inside my list as well.

Comment: Try using regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps it would depend on the pattern you're expecting? You could split on the spacing between the number and the rest of the string if that's your expected pattern:

```
s="Lines: 67 \n\nThis is an example"
m=re.match('(^Lines: \d+)\s+(.*$)', s)
print(m.groups())
# ('Lines: 67', 'This is an example')
```

With string split:

```
s="Lines: 67 \n\nThis is an example"
s.split(' \n\n', 1)
# ['Lines: 67', 'This is an example']
```

Or regex split:

```
s="Lines: 67 \n\nThis is an example"
re.split(' \s+', s, maxsplit=1)
# ['Lines: 67', 'This is an example']
```

Comment: Will mark as answer after 7minutes. Dont know why need to wait 7 minutes

Comment: is it possible to use split?

Comment: Yes, if you know the delimiter. Added an example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you always want to strip the "Line: number" section of a line you can use regex in the following way:

```
>>> import re
>>> strings = "Lines: 67 \n\nThis is an example"
>>> result = re.search("(Lines: \d+)([\s\S]+)", strings)
>>> result[1]
'Lines: 67'
>>> result[2]
' \n\nThis is an example'
>>>
```

We can break the regex pattern `(Lines: \d+)([\s\S]*)` down like so:

We want two capture groups, one representing the "Line: number" section, one for the rest of the string: `(capturegroup1)(capturegroup2)`

`Lines:` will match the beginning part and `\d` will get any digit. `+` will find one or more occurrences of the preceding `\d`.

This makes our first capture group `(Lines: \d+)`

Next we need the rest of the string, which includes `\n` characters so we can look for anything that matches `\s`, a whitespace character as well as any `\S`, a not whitespace character. To look for either we join those in a set: `[\s\S]` and look for any number of occurences of that set with `*`.

You can use a tool like https://regexr.com/ to help you along with more situations.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do it without the usage of regex:

```
string = "Lines: 67 \n\nThis is an example"
strlist = string.split()
firstresult = strlist[0] + ' ' + strlist[1]
secondresult = string.split(firstresult)[1].strip(' ')
output = [firstresult, secondresult]
print (output)
>>> ["Lines: 67", "\n\nThis is an example"]
```

If you wish to remove the `\n`:

```
secondresult = string.split(firstresult)[1].strip()
output = [firstresult, secondresult]
print (output)
>>> ["Lines: 67", "This is an example"]
```